# C# Microsoft.Interop.Document.Save() not failing in Office Word 2010

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm attempting to Save a document via WebDAV in Word 2010, but on failure no Exception is thrown. I know there's a failure since (for debugging) I'm forcing an HTTP 500 to be returned from the Apache server on PUT.

This works in Office 2007.
I suspect Microsoft Office Upload Center is intercepting the callback.
I've also checked Document.Saved property and that's set to "true".

So, it seems I have no way of detecting when there's a failed Save() event.
I'm also unable to find a way to interrogate Microsoft Office Upload Center as a possible alternative to check there instead.

Has anyone found a way to catch Document Save failures?

I'm using .Net Framework 3.5 and VSTO.

Update:
I found that checking/enabling "Delete files from the Office Document Cache when they are closed" in Microsoft Office Upload Center allows the exception to appear on document close, but not document save. Adding this in case it helps someone in the future.